# Float and Integer numbers EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Hi I am trying to do an EditText that only accepts float or integer numbers. I am doing like that but not works fine:

```
myedit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);

myedit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

I have also write like that:

```
if(!myedit.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z? ]*"){
   //do something
}
else{
 //no correct values
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set input filter to the edit text...

```
            et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                 new DigitsKeyListener(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE) {
                int beforeDecimal = 5, afterDecimal = 2;

                @Override
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                    String temp = et.getText() + source.toString();

                    if (temp.equals(".")) {
                        return "0.";
                    }
                    else if (temp.toString().indexOf(".") == -1) {
                        // no decimal point placed yet
                        if (temp.length() > beforeDecimal) {
                            return "";
                        }
                    } else {
                        temp = temp.substring(temp.indexOf(".") + 1);
                        if (temp.length() > afterDecimal) {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }

                    return super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this is late, but possibly it may help someone else stuck with this.

The easiest way I have found to accomplish this is to set the android:input value like so:

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
```

- "numberDecimal" - means that it will accept floating point numbers.
- "numberSigned" - means it will accept positive & negative numbers.

This ^^^ combination will only allow users to enter integers or floating point numbers!

Then if you wish to parse this value you may want to try something like this:

```
String numberAsString = "22.13";
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    try {
        float number = Float.parseFloat(numberAsString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Not float value", e);
        Log.e(TAG, "Not integer value", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with

`android:input = "number"` in your xml file.

This will set your edit text to get numbers only as input

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to just set the `digits` attribute to accept only valid integer and decimal values:

```
android:digits="0123456789."
```

Although you probably still should wrap the conversion in a try/catch for `NumberFormatException` just in case there's some edge entry case I'm not aware of.